# String hashing function that will produce identical results in Delphi and PHP

Tags: php, delphi, hash, delphi-xe2

I need a string hashing function that will produce identical results in Delphi XE2 and PHP. 
What are my options? Preference will be given to a free, simple and cryptographically secure solution.

Comment: Do you need the hash to be cryptographically secure or just something for error-detection?

Comment: Cryptographically secure would be good but it's not essential.

Comment: Since there are many free and simple implementations of cryptographically secure hash algorithms in nearly all languages, you can well make that essential then :)

Comment: Thanks Tibor. I've added cryptographically secure to the requirements. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can try the SHA1, crc32 or md5 algorithms all these are part of the PHP core and also  exist a lot of Delphi implementations.

- PHP [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), [crc32](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php), [md5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)
- Delphi [Delphi Encryption Compendium (DEC)](http://code.google.com/p/delphidec/) (MD5, SHA-1)
- Delphi [SynCrypto](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrypto.pas) (MD5, SHA-1)
- Delphi [TurboPower LockBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/) (MD5, SHA-1)
- Delphi *JwsclCryptProvider* unit part of the [Jwscl library (JEDI Windows Security Code Lib)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) (MD5, SHA-1)

Comment: Note, that you should generally avoid MD5 unless there is a specific reason to use it as it is considered broken by the cryptographic community nowadays.

Comment: Indeed, the MD5 algorithm is not suitable for applications like SSL certificates or digital signatures but still usable for some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried common hash functions like `\sha1()`?